# How to call user32.dll's EnumDisplaySettingsA in go

Tags: go, winapi, user32

I'm trying to get display information through Win32 APIs. So far I've managed EnumDisplayDevicesA just fine, but EnumDisplaySettingsA is giving me trouble.

No matter how I set the first two variables, the function returns zero (indicating failure), with no extra information on *why* it's failing.

Here's a cut down version of my code with just the function in question;

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    dll                 = syscall.MustLoadDLL("user32.dll")
    enumDisplaySettings = dll.MustFindProc("EnumDisplaySettingsA")
)

type devMode struct {
    dmDeviceName       [32]uint16
    dmSpecVersion      uint16
    dmDriverVersion    uint16
    dmSize             uint16
    dmDriverExtra      uint16
    dmFields           uint32
    dmOrientation      int16
    dmPaperSize        int16
    dmPaperLength      int16
    dmPaperWidth       int16
    dmScale            int16
    dmCopies           int16
    dmDefaultSource    int16
    dmPrintQuality     int16
    dmColor            int16
    dmDuplex           int16
    dmYResolution      int16
    dmTTOption         int16
    dmCollate          int16
    dmFormName         [32]uint16
    dmLogPixels        uint16
    dmBitsPerPel       uint32
    dmPelsWidth        uint32
    dmPelsHeight       uint32
    dmDisplayFlags     uint32
    dmDisplayFrequency uint32
    dmICMMethod        uint32
    dmICMIntent        uint32
    dmMediaType        uint32
    dmDitherType       uint32
    dmReserved1        uint32
    dmReserved2        uint32
    dmPanningWidth     uint32
    dmPanningHeight    uint32
}

func queryDisplaySettings() devMode {
    out := devMode{}
    out.dmSize = uint16(unsafe.Sizeof(out))
    outptr := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&out))

    namePtr := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(nil))

    var iModeNum uint32 = 4294967295
    enumCurrentSettings := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&iModeNum))

    ret, _, _ := enumDisplaySettings.Call(namePtr, enumCurrentSettings, outptr)
    if ret == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("Failed EnumDisplaySettings")
    }
    return out
}

func main() {
    settings := queryDisplaySettings()

    fmt.Printf("\n%v\n", settings.dmPelsWidth)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", settings.dmPelsHeight)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n\n", settings.dmDisplayFrequency)
}
```

My Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaysettingsw
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-devmodea
- https://github.com/JamesHovious/w32/blob/74b38b9b07b520e0f84a5eec5daada6c7b6a2471/typedef.go#L363
- https://docs.rs/winapi/0.2.0/i686-pc-windows-msvc/winapi/constant.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS.html

Comment: can you explain more on the same?

Comment: I don't quite know what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the code here.

First off your type definition of devMode is for DEVMODEW but you are calling EnumDisplaySettingsA. However you shouldn't be calling that in the first place (its the ANSI version), so use EnumDisplaySettingsW instead (UNICODE).

Next, the second parameter for EnumDisplaySettingsA/EnumDisplaySettingsW is a DWORD (uint32), however instead of passing the value, you are passing the address to it.

So replace

```
var iModeNum uint32 = 4294967295
enumCurrentSettings := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&iModeNum))
```

With just

```
iModeNum := uintptr(4294967295)
```

And it should all just work.

Comment: You sir/madam, are a lifesaver. The code now works and I can stop tearing my hair out over it, thank you!